# Repair Data for Markov Chain Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, markov-chains

As is known all probabilities need to sum up to 1. I do have a Pandas Dataframe where sometimes the probabiltiy of one event does miss.
Since I know all elements of a row need to sum up to one. I want to replace Nan by a calculated Value.
With something like the following for each row in my Pandas Data Frame

```
for item, row in df:
    df.replace(Nan,(1-sum of row())
```

As an example, here's the array I do use as testing Data the moment:

```
    matrixsum
     e    f    g
a  0.3  0.2  Nan
b  0.2  0.2  0.6
c  0.7  0.1  Nan
```

By using  df.fillna(0) i do get this:

```
  matrixsum
     e    f    g
a  0.3  0.2  0.0
b  0.2  0.2  0.6
c  0.7  0.1  0.0
```

An additional problem is the fact that only rows with `float` or `int` format can be summed to 1, but `nan` has string-formated. At the moment I just use `df.fillna(0)` but this is a bad thing to do.

Expectedt Output:

```
  matrixsum
     e    f    g
a  0.3  0.2  0.5
b  0.2  0.2  0.6
c  0.7  0.1  0.2
```

Comment: Where's the `nan` in your sample dataframe? Please share a proper one with expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your  advice, i did change the Question and tried to implement the things you asked for.

Comment: What happens if a row contains 2 ```nan```?

Comment: If a row contains more than one nan theres no Solution, and the Data cant be repaired. But i want to reduce the ammount of data the user has to enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert your dataframe to numeric values, and then fill the NaNs of each row by `1- row.sum()`:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
df = df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(1 - row.sum()), axis=1)
```

or equivalently, you can combine these two in a function:

```
def markovize(row):
    row = pd.to_numeric(row, errors="coerce")
    return row.fillna(1 - row.sum())

df = df.apply(markovize, axis=1)
```

Before:

```
     e    f    g
a  0.3  0.2  Nan
b  0.2  0.2  0.6
c  0.7  0.1  Nan
```

After:

```
     e    f    g
a  0.3  0.2  0.5
b  0.2  0.2  0.6
c  0.7  0.1  0.2
```

Comment: i did try this solution and as far as i could check it, it does work for me. I think i will accpet the Answer after some more  compatibilty checks tomorrow. Thanks for your Help and have nice Evening.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your `Nan` for all rows always appear in a single column(let's say `g`), you can do this:

Consider below `df`:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
     e    f    g
a  0.3  0.2  Nan
b  0.2  0.2  0.6
c  0.7  0.1  Nan

In [22]: df['g'] = 1 - df.sum(1)

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
     e    f    g
a  0.3  0.2  0.5
b  0.2  0.2  0.6
c  0.7  0.1  0.2
```

Comment: The missing Values are randomly distributed troughout the whole Dataset. So your Solution does not really solve my Problem right now, but i can imagine someone else might be very happy about this. Maybe i should have clarified this in my Question, so its my bad. Thanks for your Efford and your help to improve my Question text.